# What happens to the event object? Is it re-executing code?

Tags: java, swing

I am learning object oriented programming from a book. I got pretty far but now I am stuck. Is `wExec` re-executing itself? I am not sure if this is even possible. Can someone clear this up for me. When I press the button "done" and exit executing the reference object I am so confused. Here is the code from each 
class:

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class RunApp {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        MainApp app = new MainApp("hello world");
        app.showApp();
    }
}

class MainApp extends MmvcApp {
    WmvcButton btnDone;
    WmvcButton btnExit;

    public MainApp(String title) {
        super(title);
        btnDone = new WmvcButton("Done", new WmvcExecutor() {
            public void execute(ActionEvent event) {
                System.out.println("done");
                System.out.println("test 2");
            }
        });

        btnExit = new WmvcButton("Exit", btnDone.getExecutor());

    }
}

abstract class MmvcApp {
    private static JFrame frame;
    private static JPanel panel;
    private static MmvcApp singletonApp = null;

    public MmvcApp(String frameText) {
        singletonApp = this;
        initializeApp(frameText);
    }

    public void initializeApp(String frameText) {
        frame = new JFrame(frameText);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        panel = new JPanel();
        panel.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(400, 300));
        frame.add(panel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
    }

    public static JFrame getFrame() {
        return frame;
    }

    public static JPanel getPanel() {
        return panel;
    }

    public static MmvcApp getApp() {
        return singletonApp;
    }

    public void showApp() {
        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
}

class WmvcButton extends WmvcController {
    private JButton myButton;

    public WmvcButton(String compText, WmvcExecutor wExec) {
        super((JComponent) new JButton(), wExec);

        myButton = (JButton) myComponent;

        myButton.setText(compText);
        myButton.addActionListener(this);
        MmvcApp.getPanel().add(myButton);
    }
}

class WmvcController implements ActionListener {
    public JComponent myComponent;
    private WmvcExecutor wExec;

    public WmvcController(JComponent component, WmvcExecutor wExec) {
        myComponent = component;
        this.wExec = wExec;
    }

    public WmvcExecutor getExecutor() {
        return wExec;
    }

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {
        if (wExec != null) {
            wExec.execute(event);
            System.out.println("test 1");
        } else
            System.out.println("not working ");
    }
}

class WmvcExecutor {
    public void execute(ActionEvent event) {
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm sorry -- what has you confused exactly? What is your exact question?

Comment: As an aside, you will want to learn and use [Java naming conventions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Naming_convention_(programming)#Java). Variable names should all begin with a lower letter while class names with an upper case letter. Learning this and following this will allow us to better understand your code, and would allow you to better understand the code of others.

Comment: `new wmvcExecutor() { ... }` defines a new kind of **class** (specifically, an [Anonymous Class](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/anonymousclasses.html)).

Comment: how is btnExit executing btnDone code from the anonymous class

Comment: how is it happening to execute btnDone anonymous class from btnExit when btnExit only return a reference to the wmvExecutor object

Comment: And Umiarjuap Pullimmaqpaga tattaurniq nimiraq to you as well!  :D  When you initialize btnExt, you have passed it a reference to the executor retrieved from the btnDone class, so both objects ill share the same instance of the executor.

Comment: so why does it execute code again

Comment: @user2245494 by execute code again are you talking about how it prints out "Test 1" and "Test 2"?

Comment: how is it executing code at all specifically the statement System.out.println("done") not the debugin statement i made to see why is it executing code if btnDone = new WmvcButton("Done", new WmvcExecutor() {
            public void execute(ActionEvent event) {
                System.out.println("done");
                System.out.println("test 2");
            }
        });

Comment: how does  btnExit = new wmvcButton("Exit",btnDone.getExecutor()); execute the line of code public void execute(ActionEvent event) { System.out.println("done"); }

Comment: thats what im asking

Comment: if it only return a reference to the to the shared object

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both `btnDone` and `btnExit` have the same reference to `WmvncExecuter`. In these line here:

```
btnDone = new WmvcButton("Done", new WmvcExecutor() {
    public void execute(ActionEvent event) {
        System.out.println("done");
        System.out.println("test 2");
    }
});
btnExit = new WmvcButton("Exit", btnDone.getExecutor());
```

You are overriding the `execute()` method. It's the same as making a new class and overriding it there.

```
class WmvcExecuterTest extends WmvcExecuter{
    public void execute(ActionEvent event){
        System.out.println("done");
    }
}
```

So when ever you call `execute()` from a normal `WmvnExecuter` it wont do anything, but because you override `execute()`. It will perform the new code whenever `execute()` is called from that specific instance.

Comment: i get a little bit of what your saying but its still fuzy but anyway thanks ill read your post carefully

Comment: @user2245494 this really just has to do with [Anonymous Classes](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/anonymousclasses.html) as Elliot Frisch pointed out.